# Maximum value of $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin (x)f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

Question:Maximum value of $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin (x)f(x)dx$ if $|f(x)|\le5$

My Try: I tried using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin (x)f(x)dx\le\sqrt{\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin^2(x)dx\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}f^2(x)dx}$

and using $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}f^2(x)dx \le 50\pi$. But I got a different answer (answer given is $20$). Could anyone tell me where I went wrong and how to proceed?

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but it is not the tightest bound. QC_QAOA has a good answer. To add some intuition: whenever $\sin$ is negative, what should you multiply it by to maximize the contribution to the integral? What about when $\sin$ is positive? Also note that this will hold for any function in the integrand multiplied by $f(x)$, not just $\sin(x)$.

Comment: If you are trying to optimize an expression by using chain of inequalities, then every single equality conditions need to produce the same value. Otherwise, you will have overestimated and produced a looser bound. In this one, the C-S equality condition gives $f(x) = c\sin x$, but your second estimate requires $|f(x)| = 5$. There is no such $f$ that satisfies both and therefore your bound is too crude for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
        -5 &&\sin(x)\leq 0\\
        5 && \sin(x)>0
    \end{cases}$$

Then

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\sin(x)f(x)dx=5\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}|\sin(x)|dx=10\int_0^\pi \sin(x)dx=20$$

To see that this is a maximum, note that

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\sin(x)f(x)dx\leq \left|\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\sin(x)f(x)dx\right|\leq \int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\left|\sin(x)f(x)\right|dx$$

$$=\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\left|\sin(x)|\cdot |f(x)\right|dx\leq 5\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}|\sin(x)|dx=20$$